# DND while travelling

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

Me and My friends every weekend travel for about 3 hours (each saturday and sunday). I was wondering if there was a way to play dungeons and dragons with them while travelling in the cab (for free) , on online app/website or something similar. I have looked everywhere online but am not able to find a thing

Comment: I'm not sure if we can help with this specific question, but if we can we'll need a lot more details. What type of device(s) are you working on? When you say 'cab', are you in a traditional car typically and it sounds like you have a non-player driver? What did you find when you searched online and why don't they work for you, or what did you search that didn't turn up results (there are multiple online options for tabletop gaming)? Are you playing D&D 5e or other games?

Comment: Also, what kind of Internet access do you expect to have?

Comment: Are you all in the same cab or different ones?  Do you picture this mostly being auditory or text-based (and if the latter, does anyone get car-sick trying to read while moving)?  It might be relevant to know what country/countries you are in.

Comment: @Ifusaso  by devices, i mean Mobile phones. and by cab i do mean a car, with a non player driver.

Comment: What sort of problems do you expect to run into and why would you consider this to not be possible? We're gonna need more details here. Do you wish to play in a traditional way or with an online tabletop? Imo if you want to have a traditional, in-person game then the only 2 problems I can see without thinking about this in details would be 1) stuff flying everywhere when the car brakes or turns etc, which could be solvable, and 2) people getting motion sick when trying to read something in a car (like I do), to which I'm not aware of a solution if one exists but there could be ways around

Comment: @Physnerd also depends how many people there are and the seating arrangements, I imagine it much easier to execute if there's 3 of you all in the back seat than with one of the players sitting shotgun and turning around all the time, potentially distracting the driver too

Comment: @AnnaAG https://www.buzzrx.com/blog/what-are-the-most-effective-motion-sickness-pills

Comment: @Ifusaso thanks, there's some on this list that I haven't tried before, I tend to be able to normally get my motion sickness under control with a large-ish dose of dramamine but any attempt to read, do things on a tablet or really do anything else than stare straight ahead at the road will still trigger a bout without fail so if any of them is like me, they can forget about anything other than theater of mind